# Station isn't long enough?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

In RollerCoaster Tycoon 3: Platinum, after I finished building my rollercoaster, I couldn't open it because I got the message "Station isn't long enough". What does that mean and how can I fix it?[image: The Ride]

Comment: Make the station longer?

Comment: Or even have a station to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RCT1 and RCT2, the stations needed to be at least 6 blocks in length. I am not sure about minimum requirements in RCT3, but I would assume them to be same as the predecessors.

It would help if you can provide a screen-shot of the current construction.

---

A station would look something like:

[image]

Comment: you could have station platforms of 1 block as long as it was a type of ride that allowed 1 - 2 car trains, otherwise the minimum was 2.. RCT3 is the same.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Image added.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow You don't have a station at all.